# How do I separate data collected in one column into like columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, mac

I have a data base that exports data in csv format. It exports Items provided in comma separated format. However,The data does not always follow the same order of entry. I want to be able to separate that data into like columns.

We need to be able to count each "item provided" category separately.

The only way I am successful in getting the data into separate like columns is to place commas as separators to use tab delimited.  This will separate the data into like columns. For example, all forklift class will be in the same column, GED Class etc.

Our export is usually 2000 rows or more, so placing commas in each one is unrealistic.

I however know of no other way to make this happen.

[image: data]

Comment: It's not clear what the output should be, given that sample data.

Comment: Data --> Text to Columns, with a comma delimiter?  What have you tried? What do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: So in other words, if there is one particular entry, it should always go into a particular column? Is there any way you can change the way your database exports the data? This is quite an unusual, irregular way to shape the data. Probably one could write a (shell, cmd, Python, awk, …) script or Excel macroto reshape the data.

Comment: This is an export from Link2Feed, which is cloud based. They are currently working on a new way to gather and export this data but it will be months... I uploaded how I currently spend hours doing a 3 step process

Comment: Do you have a list of the “item provided” categories in advance? How do you identify (distinguish between) categories? For example, why are “Dollars & Sense Class (1)” and “Dollars & Sense Follow Up (1)” in the same column, but “Dollars & Sense Gift Card (1)” is in a different one?

Comment: If your end goal is just a count of the different items, you could split the initial CSV, then combine them all into a single column, and finally generate a pivot table to do the counts.  Or you could generate this in VBA fairly simply.

Comment: Scott, the reason they are in different columns is because what you do not see is that it exported for each client.. Some receive the service others get other services.

Comment: If you have a list of all the possible values, transpose this so it is the first row, starting at column B - with your CSV data in column A starting at row 2.  Then you can do a simple IF test to show if the heading value surrounded by commas exists in your list:  =IFERROR(IF(FIND("," &B$1&",",","&$A2&",")>0,B$1,""),"").  Drag this across all columns and down all rows.  It will insert nothing in column if matching value not found, or heading value if it is found.  You can then just copy and paste to make it static text if you prefer.